# Scrolling uiTextField for different keyboard sizes

Tags: ios, keyboard, uipickerview, accessoryview

I have a `UITableView` with a number of `UITextFields`. When the user edits the `textfields`, the `textfield` that is the `firstresponder` is scrolled to the position just above the keyboard. This works fine for `textfields` that use the default keyboard. But I have one `textfield` that is using a `UIPickerView` as inputView. Because I want the user to confrm the selection in the `pickerview` I also added a `accessoryview` with a done-button to the `inputAccessoryView` of the `textfield`.

Now I encounter a behaviour that I don't understand. When there is no keyboard shown and I click the textfield with the pickerview, I receive the notification for     `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`. The notification leads the the following function call:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    // handle resize of tableview frame...
}
```

The height of the keyboard (kbSize.height) is 260. This is equal to the default keyboard size of 216 + 44 for the toolbar in the `accessoryview`. The `textfield` is scrolled to a position above the toolbar in the `accessoryview`.

The strange behaviour happens when i first click a textfield with a default keyboard and than continue (without dismissing the keyboard) with the textfield with the `pickerview`. The `pickerview` is shown as expected, but the keyboard size does not change and stays 216 (notification is handled). This lead to different scroll behaviour: the `textfield` is visible behind the translucent toolbar in the `accessoryview`.

Please, can someone explain why the keyboard size is different for the pickerview in both cases.

Please, can someone tell me how to handle this in code. It is fine for me when the `textfield` is scrolled to the position behind the translucent toolbar.

Comment: In my code, instead of using `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`, I use `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` to set my variable that stores the keyboard's frame, so that I always have the current frame.

Comment: I tried the notification for UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification already. The result was the same as for UIKeyboardDidSowNotification.

Comment: I found the problem! I used UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey instead of UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey. This solved my problem and as Jsdodgers suggested I will use UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification for handling the different keyboards sizes.